# wmode - What does it mean in browser's rendering behavior?

Tags: html

Whats the actual behaviour of wmode attribute in HTML.

Any kind of technical details is accepted.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick Google search turns up [Adobe's docs #1](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/UsingFlash/help.html?content=WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7ba7.html) which explains it quite well:

> wmode attribute or parameter Value
>
> Window | Opaque | Transparent Template
>   variable: $WM
>
> Description
>
> (Optional) Lets you use the
>   transparent Flash content, absolute
>   positioning,  and layering
>   capabilities available in Internet
>   Explorer 4.0. For a list of  browsers
>   this attribute/parameter supports, see
>   Publishing Flash documents.
>
> **Window** Plays the application in its
>   own rectangular window on a web page. 
>   Window indicates that the Flash
>   application has no interaction with
>   HTML  layers and is always the topmost
>   item.
>
> **Opaque** Makes the application hide
>   everything behind it on the page.
>
> **Transparent** Makes the background of
>   the HTML page show through all the 
>   transparent portions of the
>   application and can slow animation
>   performance.
>
> **Opaque windowless and Transparent
>   windowless** Both interact with HTML 
>   layers, letting layers above the SWF
>   file block out the application. 
>   Transparent allows transparency so
>   that HTML layers below the SWF file 
>   might show through if a section of the
>   SWF file has transparency;  opaque
>   does not.
>
> The default value is Window if this
>   attribute is omitted. Applies to 
>   object only.